# Create prompt input dialog with dropdown box in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dialog

Does anyone know how can I create a prompt input dialog with dropdown box in javascript?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, you're probably going to have to use a modal box of some sort. Check out jQuery UI's modal box at http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 1):

Ya, you're probably going to have to settle for a modal... although you could style it to look pretty much the same.  Although it would be limited to being within the parent window.  But if you're ok with that, use a modal (jQuery's or whatever) and then just style it to look like what you're going for.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can not have an input dialog box like that. You will have to settle for a modal dialog box which can use styling.
Have a look at these example:
http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#examples