# Trying to get a drop down list in a Javascript pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a drop down list in a JavaScript pop up box.

```
function Start() {
    var name = prompt("Hello, What is your name?")
    if (isNaN(name)) {
        confirm("Hello " + name + "!")
        var race = prompt("What race are you? (First letter Uppercase please)")
        if (race == "Human") {
            confirm("You are a noble race that will protect his family and children when in harms     way.")
            var startTown = prompt("What is your city?")
        } else if (race == "Orc") {
            confirm("Hello Orc. Your murderous journey begins!")
        } else {}
    }
}
```

EDIT: I am trying to get the drop down list for the var startTown() function. I am trying to get a list of custom named cities in a drop down box in a JavaScript pop up

Comment: It's not possible with basic prompt. Why don't you use a modal window using jquery? Btw, similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732703/create-prompt-input-dialog-with-dropdown-box-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

The `prompt()` component can accept only text input. You cannot have a prepopulated list or something. If you need something like that, you can make use of many jQuery modal windows, I would recommend using Queness's basic [Simple jQuery Modal Window](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial) or [jQuery UI's dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) and add a `<select>` tag in the page.